# Intersection of a sequence of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \ell^2$ be a sequence in $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ such that it is linearly independend and $v_n \to u$

Let $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: W_m = \overline{\operatorname{span}} \{v_n\}_{n \geq m}$ with the property 
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}:
v_m \notin W_{m+1}
$$
Is it true that:
$$
\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty
W_m
=
\overline{span}\{u\}
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited after the first answer did not work as pointed out by [Matey Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/303603/matey-math):

Let $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be the standard basis of $\ell^2$. Then the sequence
$$
v_n := e_1 + \frac{e_2
}{n} + \frac{e_{n+2}}{n^3}$$
is linearly independent. Moreover, it converges to $e_1=:u$.

However, $e_2$ is in the closure of $W_m$ for all $m$. This can be seen by looking at the sequence $n(n+1)(v_n-v_{n+1})$ which converges to $e_2$.

In conclusion, the statement does not hold.

Comment: $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: W_m$ is closed so $u$ in each $W_m$

Comment: I made some adaptations to my argument, thanks for the hint.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: how do you prove that $v_n \notin W_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: You have that $\langle v_m, e_{n+2} \rangle = 0$ for all $m \geq n+1$. As a consequence, you have that  $\langle v, e_{n+2} \rangle = 0$ for all $v\in \text{span}\{v_m\}_{m\geq n+1}$ and thus $\langle w, e_{n+2} \rangle = 0$ for all $w \in W_{n+1}$. Therefore you have that $\|v_n - w\|\geq |\langle v_n - w, e_{n+2}\rangle| = 1/n^3$ for all $w\in W_{n+1}$.

Comment: exuse me @P.Pet i deleted immediatly my comment because i see that I'm wrong